# Type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' on Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, http

I'm trying to run an application that runs an API from "api-football" (https://www.api-football.com) and getting the error Type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' on emulator

This is my main.dart, i'm using the class FutureBuilder to run

```
// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:placar_brasileirao/api_manager.dart';
import 'package:placar_brasileirao/page_body.dart';
import 'package:placar_brasileirao/soccermodel.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text(
            'BRASILEIRÃO 2022',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0,
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder<SoccerMatch>(
            future: SoccerApi().fetchSoccerMatch(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                print((snapshot.data!).length);
                return PageBody(snapshot.data!);
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Center(
                  child: Text('${snapshot.error}'),
                );
              }
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I created a class SoccerMatch

```
class SoccerMatch {
  Fixture fixture;
  Team home;
  Team away;
  Goal goal;

  SoccerMatch(
      {required this.fixture,
      required this.home,
      required this.away,
      required this.goal});

  factory SoccerMatch.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return SoccerMatch(
        fixture: Fixture.fromJson(json['fixture']),
        home: Team.fromJson(json['teams']['home']),
        away: Team.fromJson(json['teams']['away']),
        goal: Goal.fromJson(json['goals']));
  }
}

class Fixture {
  int id;
  String date;
  Status status;

  Fixture({required this.id, required this.date, required this.status});

  factory Fixture.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Fixture(
        id: json['id'],
        date: json['date'],
        status: Status.fromJson(json['status']));
  }
}

class Status {
  int elapsedTime;
  String long;

  Status({required this.elapsedTime, required this.long});

  factory Status.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Status(elapsedTime: json['elapsedTime'], long: json['long']);
  }
}

class Team {
  int id;
  String name;
  String logoUrl;
  bool winner;

  Team(
      {required this.id,
      required this.name,
      required this.logoUrl,
      required this.winner});

  factory Team.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Team(
        id: json['id'],
        name: json['name'],
        logoUrl: json['logoUrl'],
        winner: json['winner']);
  }
}

class Goal {
  int home;
  int away;

  Goal({required this.home, required this.away});

  factory Goal.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Goal(home: json['home'], away: json['away']);
  }
}
```

and this is my API manager:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:placar_brasileirao/soccermodel.dart';



class SoccerApi {

  Future<SoccerMatch> fetchSoccerMatch() async {
    var headers = {
      'x-rapidapi-host': 'v3.football.api-sports.io',
      'x-rapidapi-key': 'c15180946e4982c30d9b63bc534d5f3c'
    };

    var request = http.Request('GET', Uri.parse('https://v3.football.api-sports.io/fixtures/rounds?season=2021&league=39'));

    request.headers.addAll(headers);

    http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();


    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final responseData = await response.stream.bytesToString();
      print(responseData);
      return SoccerMatch.fromJson(jsonDecode(responseData));
    }
    else {
      print(response.reasonPhrase);
      throw Exception('Failed to load album');
    }
  }
}
```

my screen when I try to run the code:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFsGo.png

Comment: Hmm, I see only API error messages in your screenshot. First of all, this certainly does not help reading the response. :-) .... It would be nice to see the response String.

In general, you certainly know that all your .fromJson methods should really get a Map<String, dynamic> as an argument. The error message suggests that you are trying to send null (because probably the key is not part of the response map) to a method expecting a map.

Comment: The api response says that you have reached the daily request limit so `response == []`. But I think the api is not sending the right response code (probably sending 200). Try to print the response code so you will know how to deal with the error.

Comment: your response from api is null and you null variabel cant be map<String, dynamic>, try debug your network or api using postman

Comment: @fsbelinda the response: https://i.imgur.com/S6k4ThW.png

Comment: @Andreas the response: https://i.imgur.com/S6k4ThW.png

Answer (score 0):

Try to use-> all the places.

```
 factory Status.fromJson(dynamic json) {
 return Status(elapsedTime: json['elapsedTime'], long: json['long']);
 }
```

Instead of

```
factory Status.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
return Status(elapsedTime: json['elapsedTime'], long: json['long']);
}
```